# Dependency errors when trying to install kodi

Tags: apt

This error occurs and I cannot do anything.

```
# apt-get install kodi
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu3) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu3) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu3) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 is to be installed
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (>= 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: kodi-bin (< 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-bluez but it is not going to be installed or
                 python-lightblue but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-simplejson but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libnfs8 but it is not going to be installed or
                 libnfs4 but it is not installable or
                 libnfs1 but it is not installable
        Depends: libshairplay0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libcec4 but it is not going to be installed
 php5-gd : Depends: phpapi-20121212+lfs but it is not installable
           Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you try `apt-get -f install` as the error suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

to get the unmet dependencies. This command should them install automatically.